# Ampscript : can't check dates

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I'm stuck on something I can't understand for now. It might be a silly thing...
I want to compare some dates on a Cloud Page, in this way :

```
    %%[
var @localDate
set @localDate = SystemDateToLocalDate(Now(1))

set @s01 = '2022-4-8 12:00:00 PM'
set @e01 = '2022-4-8 11:59:59 PM'

set @s02 = '2022-4-9 12:00:00 AM'
set @e02 = '2022-4-9 11:59:59 AM'

  ]%%
   locale date : %%=v(@localDate)=%%<br>
  %%[

 IF @localDate > @s01 AND @localDate < @e01 THEN
 
 ]%%
   1st condition
 %%[

 ELSEIF
  @localDate > @s02 AND @localDate < @e02 THEN
 
 ]%%
   2nd condition
 %%[

 ELSE
  ]%%
  
   Nothing
  
 %%[
 ENDIF
 ]%%
```

When I run it, it shows me :

```
locale date : 4/9/2022 9:07:36 AM
2nd condition
```

which is great as it's really 4/9/2022 9:07:36 AM here

However, in order to test my first condition, I wanted to change the second line of my code with 4/8/2022 3:00:00 PM

```
set @localDate = '4/8/2022 3:00:00 PM'
```

But with this I can't enter in my first condition. I always have the very last 'nothing' showing :

```
locale date : 4/8/2022 3:00:00 PM
Nothing
```

Do you see what I'm missing please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to align your data types.  You're comparing dates and strings:

```ampscript
%%[
set @localDate = SystemDateToLocalDate(Now(1))
set @localDate = dateparse('4/8/2022 3:00:00 PM')
set @s01 = dateparse('2022-4-8 12:00:00 PM')
set @e01 = dateparse('2022-4-8 11:59:59 PM')
set @s02 = dateparse('2022-4-9 12:00:00 AM')
set @e02 = dateparse('2022-4-9 11:59:59 AM')

output(concat("<br>localDate: ", @localDate))
output(concat("<br>s01: ", @s01))
output(concat("<br>e01: ", @e01))
output(concat("<br>s02: ", @s02))
output(concat("<br>e02: ", @e02))
]%%

%%[ IF @localDate > @s01 AND @localDate < @e01 THEN ]%%

<br>1st condition

%%[ ELSEIF @localDate > @s02 AND @localDate < @e02 THEN ]%%

<br>2nd condition

%%[ ELSE ]%%

<br>Nothing

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

**Output**:

```
localDate: 4/8/2022 3:00:00 PM
s01: 4/8/2022 12:00:00 PM
e01: 4/8/2022 11:59:59 PM
s02: 4/9/2022 12:00:00 AM
e02: 4/9/2022 11:59:59 AM
1st condition
```

**Reference**: [Dateparse](https://ampscript.guide/dateparse)

**Output**: [MCSnippet](https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/wfVKiuyB)

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you so much, I'll try this ! Does that mean my initial test (comparing the SystemDateToLocalDate with my String) was just working by accident ?